# How to load N records through ssis package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

i have to load the three day of data from source server to destination server through SSIS package. i have counted the total record for the three day is around 31000.

[image]

in the source table i am using the following sql query:-

select id  ,customer_id ,deleted_date  ,lc_contact_date  ,lc_lead_date  ,lc_customer_date  ,
is_blacklisted_date ,modified_date ,modified_by  ,cd_mdm1 ,cd_mdm2 ,cd_mdm3 ,cd_mdm4 ,cd_mdm5 from customer_dates WHERE (modified_date > '2018-05-25 13:32:36' and modified_date <= CURRENT_DATE-1) ;

to send the data to the destination table.

query is correct its has the around 31000 counts. but Error is while using the package its not transferring the data from source to destination. if i use limit around 600 i.e the below query its working fine.
select id  ,customer_id ,deleted_date  ,lc_contact_date  ,lc_lead_date  ,lc_customer_date  ,
is_blacklisted_date ,modified_date ,modified_by  ,cd_mdm1 ,cd_mdm2 ,cd_mdm3 ,cd_mdm4 ,cd_mdm5 from customer_dates WHERE (modified_date > '2018-05-25 13:32:36' and modified_date <= CURRENT_DATE-1) limit 600;

Can anyone help me out what setting or any thing i have to embedded to the ssis package?

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting? i assume it a data issue in a particular column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used SSIS to load millions of rows - there is no row limit in the tool.

My best guess is that something in the data conversion component is failing to cast and that is causing the package to error out.

To confirm
* remove your existing Data Viewer (optional)
* Add a Derived Column to the Error path from the existing Data Conversion component
* Add a Data Viewer between the Data Conversion and the Derived Column.

Now, all the failing rows will be directed to your viewer. At this point, you can identify why the rows are failing the specified conversion and then clean them up as needed.